# Border Color of GroupBox Control

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I change the border color of a GroupBox control in a windows application?

Answer (score 0):

The windows groupbox doesnt have a border color property, so this means you will have to create a new class inheriting from groupbox and create your own border color property. here is the code you will need;

```
    public class MyGroupBox : GroupBox
    {
        private Color _borderColor = Color.Black;

        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get { return this._borderColor; }
            set { this._borderColor = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //get the text size in groupbox
            Size tSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Text, this.Font);

            Rectangle borderRect = e.ClipRectangle;
            borderRect.Y = (borderRect.Y + (tSize.Height / 2));
            borderRect.Height = (borderRect.Height - (tSize.Height / 2));
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, borderRect, this._borderColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);

            Rectangle textRect = e.ClipRectangle;
            textRect.X = (textRect.X + 6);
            textRect.Width = tSize.Width;
            textRect.Height = tSize.Height;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), textRect);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), textRect);
        }
    }
```

after adding this code to your project click build solution, then `MyGroupBox` will appear in your toolbox to be able to use

Comment: WhatsThePoint, this is close to what I want, but I'm having two issues that I can't figure out: 1) The Group Box Name is missing and 2) all of the controls within the group box have the dark border as well - how do I get the name back and just have the modified border around the group box itself without affecting the controls inside of it? (By the way, I was getting weird doubling of the lables' text, so I had to comment out everything except the ControPaint line)